# Given a CloudTableQuery / DataServiceQuery, return associated TableServiceContext

Tags: c#, azure, wcf-data-services, azure-table-storage

Given a `CloudTableQuery` and/or `DataServiceQuery`, is it possible to get the `TableServiceContext` that produced the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using reflection. Here is an extension method that will do it for each IQueryable (supporting both CloudTableQuery and DataServiceQuery):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient;

public static class DataServiceQueryExtensions
{
    public static TableServiceContext GetTableServiceContext<TType>(this IQueryable<TType> query)
    {
        var contextField = query.Provider.GetType().GetField("Context", (BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
        if (contextField == null)
            return null;
        else
            return contextField.GetValue(query.Provider) as TableServiceContext;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Sandrino

Comment: I'm going to hold out for a magical solution that doesn't require using private members via reflection, but otherwise I'll mark this as the answer.